# Utilizando Jekyll criando um for de noticias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

Estou com a seguinte duvida como eu crio um for de noticias? Tenho que adicionar alguma coisa dentro do arquivo config.yml?

Dentro da pasta _post eu tenho o arquivo 2015-03-03-welcome-jekyll.markdown

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Welcome to Jekyll!"
date:   2015-03-03 14:47:43
categories: "jekyll update"
---
```

Se eu fizer assim em inha view

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:20 %}  
            <li>  
                <span>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span> &raquo;  
                <a href="{{ BASE_PATH }}{{ post.url }}">  
                     {{ post.title }}
                </a>  
            </li>  
{% endfor %}
```

Funciona certo, mas se eu renomear a pasta _posts para _notices e mudar no loop de site.posts para site.notices e rodar ele não funciona. Minha duvida é como eu consigo criar noticias, depoimentos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Jekyll existe um conceito chamado "collections". Um exemplo é a coleção de `post` que é criada por default com os arquivos do diretório `_post`.

Para criar uma nova coleção você precisa declará-la no `_config.yml`. Por exemplo:

```yaml
collections:
  news:
    output: true
# outras configurações...
```

Os arquivos devem ficar em um diretório `_news`.

Confira a documentação para mais opções na geração dos arquivos e customização do formato: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/